# Node-insert check and alter value of other entities

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I have a site I'm building where the admin can add sale "specials" (sales) to a store.  So there's the store content type - and the sales are entity references appended to the store.

Each "special/sale" has a start/stop date - naturally.

What the client would like to have is for the system to (upon insert of the new node) adjust the other sale dates if they conflict.

So imagine there's:

Sale 1: 1-01-2015 -> 1-15-2015
Sale 2: 1-16-2015 -> 1-30-2015

And now they insert a new sale with the dates of 1-13-2015 -> 1-25-2015

They'd like the end result to be where previously created sales 1 and 2 are now adjusted to:

Sale 1: 1-01-2015 -> 1-12-2015
Sale 2: 1-26-2015 -> 1-30-2015
(new Sale 3): 1-13-2015 -> 1-25-2015

How would I best go about doing that (checking other attached entity references and adjusting the date ranges for them).

Thanks!

Comment: I would try to convince your client that it's a bad idea. What if a store owner has different types of Sales: a shoe sale, then a pants sale - each with overlapping dates - by your method it would force the store to change their sale dates, even if they chose those dates specifically to overlap

Comment: I agree with your thought process - but actually in this case it's a non issue.  There really is only one type of "sale" - believe it or not.  The only difference between one range and another is the price it's being offered at.

Comment: Maybe a better way for me to have explained it is rather instead of it being the "store" that has the date ranges/sales appended to it - it's the product itself.  So say it's a shoe...that shoe is being offered at $X price for this date range...$Y price at the next range...etc.

Comment: it sounds like you would need to override hook_node_save() to then go through every sale node for the current store - but you're going to have to develop an algorithm to determine the date changes, and that's probably too involved for here

Comment: Agreed.  Now here's my more generic question...  I've never really mucked around with this type of functionality within the drupal framework.  I know exactly how I'd do it, however, via straight PHP/MySQL.

Comment: Can I just manually go into the database, search by entity reference, adjust the values via MySQL and be done with it?

Comment: there are more 'Drupal' ways of doing it, like node_load - even if you go straight throught the DB, use the drupal functions to do it (a search will give you all you need) - this is for security reasons, since the functions are already set to check for XSS attacks, etc. There are a number of tutorial for direct sql access the 'Drupal' way